# adding a new row in pandas based on a certain condition? python

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to use pd.apply() to add a new row if the isinstance(x, list) is True
So for instance, can I make idx 57 into three different rows in the same dataframe?

Currently:

```
56    the University of Notre Dame
57    [Berkeley, Columbia Business School, Haas]
```

Desired:

```
56    the University of Notre Dame
57    Berkeley
58    Columbia B School
59    Haas  


AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1121-0cd6253a0f30> in <module>()
     15 s = pd.Series(["the University of Notre Dame", ["Berkeley", "Columbia Business School", "Haas"]])
     16 
---> 17 s.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x)).stack().reset_index(drop=True)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'stack'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
In [106]: s = pd.Series(["the University of Notre Dame", ["Berkeley", "Columbia Business School", "Haas"]])

In [107]: s
Out[107]: 
0                  the University of Notre Dame
1    [Berkeley, Columbia Business School, Haas]
dtype: object

In [110]: s.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
Out[110]: 
0    the University of Notre Dame
1                        Berkeley
2        Columbia Business School
3                            Haas
dtype: object
```

Comment: hhm, i keep getting series object has no attribute stack?

Comment: No need for `.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))`; that's the same as `.apply(pd.Series)`.

Comment: Thanks DSM! @user3314418 that would be a sign that the apply did not create a dataframe. Are you sure there are lists in your series?

Comment: What version of pandas do you have?

Comment: i have version '0.12.0'

Comment: upgrading now with pip install --upgrade pandas

Comment: do i have to restart my python kernel to get the update to take effect? when i type pd.__version__ it remains at .12.0

Comment: hm. I keep getting this error: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1

Comment: Does it say anything more? To be sure, close all python processes when upgrading. Do you have the correct rights?

Comment: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/x8/dmmzl8kd2lx4k24lb6fkqx300000gn/T/pip_build_AJ/pandas
Storing complete log in /Users/AJ/.pip/pip.log